# Highstock rendering issue - Series from different charts get rendered in the same chart

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, highcharts

I'm using Highstock + Highchart-more to render a Line Chart of AVG temperature in a div and a windrose in another div.
I got some strange behaviours in Chrome, Safari and Firefox:
**Issue n.1: [SOLVED, SEE MY OWN ANSWER BELOW]


Chrome and Safari**
When loading the page for the first time i get the Highstock navigator of the Temperature chart begin from a date where no data can be found and, on the leftmost part of the chart, i see the windrose series: 
[image]

After dragging the navigator to the chart start or reloading the chart from a valid start date, everyhing looks fine:
[image]

This weird thing doesn't happen in Firefox.

**Issue n.2**
 [STILL UNSOLVED]
**Chrome, Safari, Firefox**
When resizing the window, the chart changes, both in X and Y scale and become this:
[image]

I really can't find where the trouble is...

I grab my datasources with an ajax call to a php controller and pass them as Json and render the charts with custom wrappers.

Here's the JS custom lib i use (other these :

```
function createTempChartTable(tempChartContainer, tempChartDataSource, tempTableJSVar, TempTableDataSource, reload, chartType, dates) {
seriesCounter = 0;
serieSrc = [];
jQuery.each(names, function(i, name) {
    jQuery.get(tempChartDataSource + dates[0] + '/' + dates[1] + '/' + name, function(
            data) {
        jQuery.each(data['data'], function(i, values) {
            serieSrc[seriesCounter] = {
                name : name,
                data : values
            }
        });
        seriesCounter++;
        if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
            createChart(tempChartContainer, serieSrc);
            if (reload)
            tempoTableJSVar.fnReloadAjax(tempoTableDataSource + dates[0] + '/' + dates[1] + '/');
        }
    });
});
```

}

```
function createChart(chartContainer, serieSrc) {
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
months: ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'],
weekdays: ['Domenica', 'Luned√¨', 'Marted√¨', 'Mercoled√¨', 'Gioved√¨', 'Venerd√¨', 'Sabato'],
shortMonths : [ 'Gen', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mag', 'Giu', 'Lug', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Ott', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
}
});
chartTempH24 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: { renderTo: chartContainer,  zoomType: 'x' },
    rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [{ type : 'hour', count : 1, text : '1h'  },
                       { type : 'day', count : 1, text : '1D'   },
                       { type : 'all', count : 1, text : 'All'  }
                      ],
            selected : 2
    },
    series:  serieSrc
    });
```

}

```
function createWindChartTable(chartContainer,chartDataSource, tableJSVar, tableDataSource, reload, chartType, dates) {
// dati dei venti
directionCounter = 0;
serieString ='';
serieSrc = [];
jQuery.get(chartDataSource + from + '/' + to + '/' + venti[0] + '/'
        + venti[1], function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data['data'], function(grado, indexArr) {

        for (i=0;i<indexArr.lenght;i++)
            indexArr[i] = Number(indexArr[i].toFixed(1));


        serieSrc[directionCounter] = {
            name : grado,
            data : indexArr
        }

        directionCounter++;
        if (directionCounter == BeaufortDegrees) {
            createWindRose(chartContainer, chartType, serieSrc);

            if(reload)
                tableJSVar.fnReloadAjax(tableDataSource + dates[0] + '/' + dates[1]+ '/');
        }
    });
});
```

}

```
function createWindRose(chartContainer, chartType, serieSrc){

chartVh24 = new Highcharts.Chart({      
    chart: { polar: true, type: chartType, renderTo : chartContainer },             
    legend: { reversed: true, align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'top', y: 100, layout: 'vertical' },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['N','NNE','NE','ENE', 'E','ESE','SE','SSE','S','SSW','SW','WSW','W','WNW','NW','NNW'],
        labels:{rotation: 'auto'}
    },
    yAxis: {

    },
    tooltip: { followPointer: true },
    plotOptions:{
        series: { stacking: 'normal', shadow: false, groupPadding: 0, pointPlacement: 'on' }
    },
    series: serieSrc.reverse()
});
```

}

Thank you for the help!
Lorenzo

EDIT: 
TempChartSerie  = 
`serieSrc per Temperature
[{name: 'min10_AirTC_Avg',data:[1359558300000,,1364405400000,98.871,1364405401000,-8.74335,1364410800000,98.226,1364410801000,-9.33595,1364416200000,97.718,1364416201000,-9.56538,1364421600000,97.312,1364421601000,-9.90062,1364427000000,97.054,1364427001000,-10.2689,1364432400000,96.77,1364432401000,-10.6219,1364437800000,96.625,1364437801000,-10.3702,1364443200000,95.922,1364443201000,-11.0126,1364448600000,91.254,1364448601000,-7.29045,1364454000000,79.84,1364454001000,-3.75038,1364459400000,81.826,1364459401000,-4.95188,1364464800000,90.082,1364464801000,-4.02362,1364470200000,89.332,1364470201000,-4.85343,1364475600000,96.914,1364475601000,-5.66058,1364481000000,98.228,1364481001000,-5.90878,1364486400000,98.535,1364486401000,-6.61818,1364491800000,98.824,1364491801000,-6.48165,1364497200000,99.189,1364497201000,-6.08515,1364502600000,99.64,1364502601000,-5.45207,1364508000000,99.882,1364508001000,-5.21893,1364513400000,99.998,1364513401000,-4.797,1364518800000,99.998,1364518801000,-4.04547,1364524200000,99.998,1364524201000,-3.8185,1364529600000,99.998,1364529601000,-3.68492,1364535000000,99.998,1364535001000,-3.57873,1364540400000,99.586,1364540401000,-1.41212,1364545800000,97.688,1364545801000,0.718517,1364551200000,97.262,1364551201000,0.8715,1364556600000,97.136,1364556601000,-1.56103,1364562000000,98.609,1364562001000,-2.03847,1364567400000,99.402,1364567401000,-3.77712,1364572800000,99.998,1364572801000,-4.68402,1364578200000,99.998,136457...1000,-6.16965,1365568200000,85.764,1365568201000,-5.29423,1365573600000,75.254,1365573601000,-4.50132,1365579000000,72.617,1365579001000,-3.35802,1365584400000,72.974,1365584401000,-2.72162,1365589800000,73.707,1365589801000,-2.12643,1365595200000,77.027,1365595201000,-1.42703,1365600600000,78.816,1365600601000,-2.75922,1365606000000,83.602,1365606001000,-3.42327,1365611400000,87.216,1365611401000,-3.92763,1365616800000,88.4,1365616801000,-3.97052,1365622200000,95.654,1365622201000,-5.09757,1365627600000,87.703,1365627601000,-4.07203,1365633000000,92.338,1365633001000,-4.0868,1365638400000,92.02,1365638401000,-4.05112,1365643800000,96.738,1365643801000,-4.26392,1365649200000,90.718,1365649201000,-3.71972,1365654600000,89.904,1365654601000,-3.59263,1365660000000,88.238,1365660001000,-0.99675,1365665400000,81.021,1365665401000,0.3062,1365670800000,79.652,1365670801000,1.5795,1365676200000,91.468,1365676201000,3.55297,1365681600000,92.688,1365681601000,1.28492,1365687000000,94.199,1365687001000,0.3689,1365692400000,99.998,1365692401000,-2.29203,1365697800000,99.998,1365697801000,-2.28558,1365703200000,99.998,1365703201000,-2.1486,1365708600000,99.998,1365708601000,-2.28017,1365714000000,99.998,1365714001000,-1.9244,1365719400000,99.998,1365719401000,-2.02197,1365724800000,99.998,1365724801000,-2.01222,1365730200000,99.998,1365730201000,-1.7501,1365735600000,99.998,1365735601000,-1.77687,1365741000000,99.998,1365741001000,-1.10027,1365746400000,99.998,1365746401000,-0.8805]}
]`

windRose serie:

```
`[{name: 'BF0',data:[3.2,0,0,0,0.4,0,0.2,0,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF1',data:[7,1.2,1.4,1.4,0.8,0.4,1,1.2,0.2,1,0,0.2,0,0.8,0.6,0.6]},
{name: 'BF2',data:[25.4,5.2,2.4,1.8,0,0,0,2.4,1,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,1.2]},
{name: 'BF3',data:[14.6,4.4,3,0.6,0,0,0,0.6,0.8,0,0,0.2,0.8,0.4,0,0.2]},
{name: 'BF4',data:[4.8,1.2,0.8,0,0.2,0,0,0.2,0,0,0,1,0.4,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF5',data:[2,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF6',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF7',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF8',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF9',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF10',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF11',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name: 'BF12',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
]`
```

As i wrote in the comments, the series are nicely separated now (it was a wrong JS variable scope to cause the clash) but, in the 'ALL' zoom settings, values seem to be 'auto-avaraged' and display values that don't match any data. In '1Day' and '1 hour' zoom, data values are fine. 
i' also checking PHP because this zoom issue takes place only when seeing data as anonymous user (**NOTE** data series pasted above are the ones used to render anonymous user charts).

 On Temp serie there a NULL value as second element of the array, this doesn't influence the other charts...

Comment: I think it would be better to see it working on jsFiddle with error. Make sure your data is sorted for xAxis ascending and doesn't contain any NaN or strings.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus, putting the code on Fiddle is not possible (at least with my Fiddle knowledge) because it uses php request on my localhost.<br> Anyway, i solved the first issue making the variables local, i'm still coping with the zoom issue on all browswers.<br>

Comment: You should be able to get your static (just copy-paste from browser created chart options with serieS) chart, which could be put into jsfiddle. Or could you share what do you have in `serieSrc` variable before chart is created? What cross to my mind, try to disable dataGrouping.

Comment: here's my TempChart data before chart rendering:

Comment: You can edit your question to add data sample. Comments are not the best place to put a lot of code :)

Comment: Hi @PawełFus, shame on me...it was simply dataGrouping...if only i read the Highstock API documentation before...Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was mistaking JS variables scope. 
Sorry for bothering without thinking about that before.

In my custom lib I used global varibles instead of locals.
Making them local solves the first issue.

Second issue was just dataGrouping...shame on me!
Hope this Q&A can help someone else dumb as me :D

Cheers!